# I get random glitches on my display when using my laptop

Tags: display

I get random screen glitches, and the only way to resolve it is putting my PC to sleep and turning it back on. I've tried editing *grub* and switching to *X11*, but it keeps happening. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

My PC specs:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP EliteBook 840 G1 A3009DD10303 
Kernel: 6.2.0-33-generic 
Uptime: 2 hours, 26 mins 
Packages: 2100 (dpkg), 18 (flatpak), 13 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru \[GTK2/3\] 
Icons: Yaru \[GTK2/3\] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-4300U (4) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT 
Memory: 3737MiB / 15409MiB
```

This is how it looks when it happens:
[image: This is how it looks when it happens]

A picture of my screen when its normal:
[image: A picture of my screen when its normal]